# Monitor only recognises the signal when started first

Tags: hdmi, boot-issues, signal

My monitor, an old Toshiba 47wlg66, will display what my boards output (whether it's my old Raspberry Pi 1 A or new Raspberry Pi 4 B) only if it was powered first. Otherwise it will remain black..

It is troublesome because I power the 2 at the same time, and the Pi's must be quicker to send their first signal because in that case the screen remains black and I need to power off and on the Pi for the monitor to recognize the signal.

I usually use `dietpi`, but have seen this behaviour with Raspbian as well. Is there a way to fix that, or at least some kind of signal I could send from a script that would tell the monitor to start listening as it does whilst booting?

Comment: Leave it all powered on!

Comment: @Dougie that won't do. People can mess with it, and I want a real fix..

Answer (score 2):

**Bullseye update**
There is now an option in `raspi-config` `Display Options` to set VNC Resolution for headless operation.

> The method below prevents other `config.txt` options from working.

---

You need to force HDMI output in `/boot/config.txt` (earlier models defaulted to composite, the Pi4 does nothing).

```
    # uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
    hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

This requires a default resolution to be set in `raspi-config` (at least on the Pi4 - earlier models defaulted to VGA resolution).

It is also possible to set resolution manually, but in `raspi-config` it is easier to select a resolution supported by your monitor.

Mine is (this selects a different resolution if the wide screen Acer is detected) -

```
#DVI DMT (35) RGB full 5:4, 1280x1024 @ 60.00Hz
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=35
[EDID=ACR-Acer_KA210HQ]
#DVI DMT (82) RGB full 16:9, 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=82
[all]
```

**NOTE** don't just blindly copy the values above - set defaults which are supported by your monitor, so it will work if the monitor is connected.

Comment: When trying to get the right resolution with the pi4, I tried setting those hdmi groups with no great success. Specifying the framebuffer_[width|height] options did do the trick along with overscan_*. I'll try again setting the hdmi_group and the force hotplug next time I am in front of the beast!

Answer (score 1):

Is it because the Pi is defaulting to a low resolution? You can try setting the default resolution (within the configuration) to match the resolution of your monitor. I forget what the default resolution is but it is much less than monitors typically are - it's probably set to target the small touchscreens.

Comment: I don't think it's related, but I set a resolution already in my config.txt.