# Screen Configuration does nothing, and nothing I do seems to change the desktop resolution in VNC

Tags: display, vnc, screen, macos

I connect to a headless Pi from my Mac. I've set resolution in raspi-config, I've manually edited /boot/config.txt, and when I select Screen Configuration at the desktop (VNC'd in from the Mac) nothing happens. I've done this all in the past, but the new lack of a screen resolution menu item means whatever I used to do no longer works. I'm sure this is a well-known issue, but I can't find any reference to it here.

64-bit Raspberry Pi OS, newly installed. Booting from SATA SSD. I installed Real VNC Server to connect (which I have to manually launch every time I reboot even after setting it up to autoload which is another irritation I need to deal with after I can get more than a postage-stamp-sized screen to work in.)

Comment: If you want help you need to explain what you **ACTUALLY** did. "I've manually edited /boot/config.txt" is meaningless.

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/113873/8697

Comment: Do you know that the 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS is an unstable beta release? Maybe you file a bug report to the developers?

Comment: @Milliways, what I _actually_ did was set the resolution in `raspi-config` and edited `/boot/config.txt` to uncomment `framebuffer_width` and `_height` and set them to 1920 and 1080 respectively. The post you referenced mentioned uncommenting `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` which must be the default now because it was already uncommented in my copy. After another pass through RPi Foundation's docs, I've also tried duplicating settings for both HDMI 0 and 1. No love—all RealVNC ever sees is 1024x768.

Comment: @Ingo, yes I'm aware that it's a beta release, but wanted to research and ensure that my issue was in fact a bug and not just an oversight on my part. I'm self-aware enough to know that it's most probably my fault.

Comment: DO NOT put details in Comments. Edit your question .

Comment: Do you have some problem with posting what the result of  "set the resolution in raspi-config" was or why you fiddled with "framebuffer_width and _height"? Did you **ACTUALLY** try following the linked Answer?