# raspberry pi - vnc viewer wrong resolution

Tags: pi-4, vnc

I know this is a old topic but even after reading dozens of comments i couldn't solve the problem. With hdmi plugged to raspberry everything is fine. When I don't plug HDMI my resolutioin is too big(in scale automatically vnc option) and small in scale to 100%. I've tried to modify parameters in config.txt but nothing. Maybe there is a conflict between config.txt and something else? I don't know I am a bit ignorant with this.

I try to post my config.txt. my uncommented rows:

```
*--uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
-- overscan.

framebuffer_width=1920

framebuffer_height=1080

--uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output

hdmi_force_hotplug=1

--uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)

#hdmi_foce_mode = 1

#hdmi_group=2

#hdmi_mode=82

dtoverlay=gpio-fan,gpiopin=14,temp=90000*
```

I also tried to uncomment hdmi parameters. but nothing. What could I do?

Thank you everyone. It's been all day i'm trying to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with my raspberry and VNC Viewer. I managed to solve it by setting up the **headless resolution** to the resolution of my screen (the one I use to connect remotely, which is 1920x1080). Open the **main menu (top left)>Preferences>Raspberry Pi Configuration>Display** and set your resolution.

It is easier to do it this way with a screen than doing it with `raspi-config`.

Comment: This option is completely ignored for me and the Screen Layout Editor only shows 640x480 as the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Don't fiddle with framebuffer (which is pointless on a Pi4)

Set the default resolution (preferably while a monitor IS connected) in `raspi-config`.
Then you will have the same resolution whether a monitor is connected or not.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/113873/8697