# Pi4: Allow boot with and without HDMI

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, display

I need to boot my Pi4 to boot with AND without a HDMI cable plugged in.
In order to boot without a monitor connected to the Pi, I've added

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

To the `config.txt`. Now the Pi boots without a monitor but as soon as I plug in the monitor again, nothing appears on it. The Pi boots, but seems not to display anything on the monitor. Is this normal behavior when adding the line, stated above?

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I'd try to add a hdmi_group and hdmi_mode to the config

Answer (score 2):

You can easily boot the Pi headless without a display - but
obviously to CLI not to a GUI.

If you want to boot to GUI without a display (e.g. to use VNC) you need to configure the Pi4 to use a default resolution. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/113873/8697

If you want to use a monitor it is preferable to configure with the monitor attached (so the resolutions match).

Comment: Thanks for answering! I did configure  hdmi_group=2, hdmi_mode=82. But still, nothing is shown on the monitor. Even if i plug it in before booting the pi. As soon as I comment out hdmi_force_hotplug=1, everything works fine again